# Issue inside of while loop with amounts

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop, pdo

I have an issue inside my while, the data is grouped by date and id user but in the total per day the amount is sum with the first amount of the next day, so the total in each day are not correct.

How can I fix this?

Here my query:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-condensed">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Username</th>
            <th>Total per day</th>
            <th>Income</th>
            <th>expenses</th>
            <th>Total</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php
            $day = 01;
            $sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT count(id) AS id, DATE_FORMAT(payDay, '%d %M %Y') AS date, DATE_FORMAT(payDay, '%d') AS day,
            SUM(total) AS total, username, SUM(amount) AS amount
            FROM INCOME WHERE active != 0 AND MONTH(payDay) = MONTH(current_date) AND YEAR(payDay) = YEAR(current_date)
            GROUP BY date ASC, id_user ASC");
            $sql->execute();
            while($row = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { 
                //sum totally at final
                $totalPerMonth += $row['total'];
                $AmountPerMonth+= $row['amount'];
                $usersPerMonth += $row['id'];
                //totally per day
                $totalPerDay += $row['total'];
                $amountPerDay += $row['amount'];
                $UserPerDay += $row['id'];
                
                $ddate = $row['day'];
                
        ?>
        <?php if($day != $ddate){ ?>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">Total per day</td>
            <td class="center"><?= $UserPerDay; ?></td>
            <td class="center"><?= number_format($totalPerDay,2,'.',','); ?></td>
            <td class="center"><?= number_format($amountPerDay,2,'.',','); ?></td>
            <td class="center"><?= number_format(($totalPerDay+$amountPerDay),2,'.',','); ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="6"> --------- </td>
        </tr>
        <?php  $UserPerDay = NULL; $totalPerDay = NULL; $amountPerDay = NULL; } ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?= $row['date']; ?></span></td>
            <td class="center"><?= $row['username']; ?></td>
            <td class="center"><?= $row['id']; ?></td>
            <td class="center"><?= number_format($row['total'],2,'.',','); ?></td>
            <td class="center"><?= number_format($row['amount'],2,'.',','); ?></td>
            <td class="center"><?= number_format($row['total']+$row['amount'],2,'.',','); ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php  $dd = $ddate; $row['total'] = NULL; $row['amount'] = NULL; } ?>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="text-center" colspan="3"><?= $usersPerMonth; ?></span></td>
            <td class="text-center" colspan="3"><?= number_format($totalPerMonth+$AmountPerMonth,2,'.',','); ?></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

So per example if the first of X month there is a 50 in total and the total in the next day is 15, in the first day sum 50 + 15...

Here capture:

[image: image capture]

Comment: @derpirscher Why would that be wrong? The difference is that the `PerDay` variables get reset whenever the date changes.

Comment: @Barmar Ah, you are right, missed that ...

Comment: You already did `$totalPerDay += $row['total'];`, before you even check whether the day is still the same, `<?php if($day != $ddate){ ?>`